# How can I test if IE6,7,8 are successfully using Flash without installing them?

Tags: flash, html5-video, ietester

I made a [HTML5 video](http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?page=codeExamples&idCode=videoresize) which plays well in all modern browsers. However, it needs to successfully "fall back to Flash" in IE6,7,8.

When I look at my site in [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) with its emulation of IE6, IE7, and IE8, these browsers play they flash version of the video as they should.

In order to see if Flash is working in IETester at all, I go to http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html which quickly displays that Flash is working, but then crashes, so I'm not really sure if IETester is showing me what users of these actual browsers see who have Flash installed.

**How can I be certain that IE6, IE7, and IE8 can successfully run the Flash version of my video without installing these browsers and flash on other machines?**

Comment: Try this website: http://www.impossibilities.com/flashinfo/ it shows which version of Flashplayer is running on the machine.

Comment: thanks, at least that site doesn't crash IETester

Answer (score 1):

I use VMWare with a fresh install of WinXP Pro (WinXP Pro comes with IE6) I created "snapshots" after I installed each Windows Service Pack and Browser upgrade. I could also do this with the OS if I wanted to upgrade to Win7 and get IE9 on my VM, but I haven't needed it yet.

I have

```
WinXP Pro IE6
WinXP Pro SP2
WinXP Pro SP2 IE7
WinXP Pro SP3 IE7
WinXP Pro SP3 IE8
```

I can start at any snapshot to create pretty much anything else I need as well. For instance WinXP Pro SP3 IE6?, I could start with WinXP Pro IE6...

Comment: where did you get your install files for IE6, IE7, IE8, I found what seems to be an official site to get these, but can't find the actual base downloads for all of the "updates and service packs", where are the official base download files for these versions?

Comment: I googled for each version (i.e. "IE7 WinXP Pro") and looked through those. That search btw yielded: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2